# Environment variables and other features are missing in InstallShield project

Tags: installshield

I have existing .ism project (InstallShield 2018R2 Professional), which contains full list of features, the project window looks like this:

[image: All features]

When I create a new project, selecting InstallScript type, the same project window is missing many features:

[image: Missing features]

Currently I am looking for Environment Variables window, but many other features are missing as well. How to get all these features enabled in the project?

It looks like my InstallShield edition supports them, since existing project looks OK. But I cannot create a new project with the same functionality.

Comment: Your existing project could be basic MSI or installscript MSI project which is different than your new project with type installscript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your existing project could be basic MSI or installscript MSI project which is different than your new project with installscript project type.